# Apache URL Rewrite for Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rest, url-rewriting, epiphany

I'm trying to achieve the following:

An HTTP request made to `subdomain.domain.com/some/path` should be rewritten to `domain.com/subdomain/api.php?__route__=some/path`.

This is the requirement in order for the Epiphany library to function and properly process RESTful API calls. My website is currently hosted on GoDaddy and I have setup `subdomain.domain.com` to point to `domain.com/subdomain` using the GoDaddy web interface. I have placed the following text in the .htaccess file under the subdomain directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ api.php?__route__=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm getting the standard 500 Internal Server Error when I try to make any calls to the RESTful API.

Unfortunately, I have to wait several hours before GoDaddy gives me access to any Apache log files. Any ideas why this isn't working?

**EDIT**

In order to clarify, I want the following rewriting to take place:

`internal.ledworld-me.com/some/path` => `ledworld-me.com/internal/api.php?__route__=/some/path`

Right now, GoDaddy is being used to map `internal.ledworld-me.com` to `ledworld-me.com/internal`. I'm starting to think I should remove the mapping from the GoDaddy side and rely solely on mod_rewrite in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/internal/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ api.php?__route__=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now I get "The requested URL `/subdomain/some/path` was not found on this server". It seems URL rewriting is not taking place. In order to clarify things and make the question less generic, the domain is ledworld-me.com and the subdomain is internal.ledworld-me.com. So what I want is that when a request is made to internal.ledworld-me.com/path it should be rewritten to ledworld-me.com/internal/api.php?__route__=/path. Please also note that the mapping of the subdomain internal.ledworld-me.com to ledworld-me.com/internal has already been setup via the GoDaddy web interface.

Comment: Can you whether both domains are sharing same `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Yes, internal.ledworld-me.com is mapped to ledworld-me.com/internal (via GoDaddy), so they share the same DocumentRoot.

Comment: Should I turn off the mapping of internal.ledworld-me.com to ledworld-me.com/internal from GoDaddy or leave it in place?

Comment: I think that should be turned off and `DocumentRoot` needs to be same for both domains.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, nothing will work. I've reduced the requirements (for now) to just performing simple subdomain rewriting i.e. internal.ledworld-me.com/test.html => ledworld-me.com/internal/test.html. I placed the following in my .htaccess file under the web root:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.ledworld-me\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [R,L]

but i simply get:
Oops! Google Chrome could not find internal.ledworld-me.com

Can you help me just set up this simple rewriting first?

Comment: If you're getting `Google Chrome could not find internal.ledworld-me.com` that means probably `internal.ledworld-me.com` DNS isn't valid. Can you ping `internal.ledworld-me.com`?

Comment: I have added a CNAME record in DNS and the ping is returning the correct host IP address. I no longer get the "could not find internal.ledworld-me.com" error but here is where I stand right now is:
1. internal.ledworld-me.com/test.html works (if test.html actually exists)
1. internal.ledworld-me.com/some/path causes a 404 not found error (if some/path does not exist). This makes sense seeing as my .htaccess file is now empty. It is GoDaddy that is doing all the rewriting at this point and I have absolutely no clue what to put in my .htaccess file to get this to work.

Comment: Ok good alteast that first hurdle is gone. Now do you want `internal.ledworld-me.com/some/path ` to be redirected to `ledworld-me.com/some/path`? Will `ledworld-me.com/some/path` not cause 404?

Comment: Since `internal.ledworld-me.com/some/path` doesn't actually exist, it should be rewritten as `ledworld-me.com/internal/api.php?__route__=/some/path`. This should only happen when /some/path doesn't exist.

Comment: ok good, that is exactly what above rule of mine is already doing. It will only rewrite when /some/path doesn't exist.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm getting "The requested URL /internal/some/path was not found on this server." This means that one of the RewriteCond's is not being met and I think it is the first RewriteCond in your code above. The condition is testing if the HOST equals `internal.ledworld-me.com`, but this will never be the case because GoDaddy has rewritten it to `ledworld-me.com` as part of the subdomain mapping no?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45551/discussion-between-faridghar-and-anubhava)

Comment: Sorry just came back online. I am not sure if Godaddy will have host part rewritten to `ledworld-me.com`. What URL do you see in your browser after not found error?